# Facebook GraphAPI: page subscribed_apps with subscribed_fields messages is not working

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I tried to subscribed apps with webhook fields `messages` by using graph api page `subscribed_pages` edge from this
[link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webhooks/#subscribe-your-page). I got the success response after POST request. And I also got the subscribed app information by using GET request as follow.
[image]
[image]

I cannot see the webhook fields `messages` in `App Dashboard->Messenger API setting -> webhook fields` text box. And my application didn't get notification message from page.

I have to subscribe `messages` manually from App dashboard. After that, my application got the notification message from page.

I would like to subscribe webhook fields by using graph API. But the problem is graph API `subscribed_pages` edge is not reflected the webhook fields in App. I am stuck in this issue. May I know any idea or possible way to use graph API for subscribed webhook fields?

Comment: Subscribing your _app_ for updates on the message field is something you need to to manually, or via the `/{app-id}/subscriptions` endpoint - that's the steps 1 to 4 under "Subscribe to Meta Webhooks", https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webhooks/#subscribe-to-meta-webhooks

Comment: Yes. I didn't notice that. thank for comment.